# rel="preload" not working in Firefox and new Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, preload

I've been using this for a long time, working in Chrome, but my customer is using this Internet Edge Explorer and I tried with Firefox and they don't show anything in the console and no css loading in the network tab. No extensions installed to the browsers.

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
      bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-aAr2Zpq8MZ+YA/D6JtRD3xtrwpEz2IqOS+pWD/7XKIw=" crossorigin="anonymous"
      onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-aAr2Zpq8MZ+YA/D6JtRD3xtrwpEz2IqOS+pWD/7XKIw=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</noscript>
```

Why does this only work in Chrome?

Comment: What do you mean "Internet Edge Explorer"? Is it Internet Explorer or Edge Legacy? You can check the [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-preload):`rel="preload"` is not supported by IE and Edge Legacy and it's not supported by Firefox by default. It is by design in different browsers.

Comment: I was having the same issue with the same preload snippet, on firefox, you can toggle the `network.preload` value to `true` on the about:config page and this works